# Twig & Yaml with Grav

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml, grav

I am currently creating a module on Grav but I have a problem.
**Yaml :**

```
table:
    -
        title: Test
        content:
            -
                value: 'test1'
            -
                value: 'test2'
            -
                value: 'test3'
```

**Twig :**

```
{% for item in page.header.table.content %}
     <h1>{{item.value}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

I can not display 'value'
but if I do :

```
{% for item in page.header.table %}
      <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

title is displayed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Table is an array of object

https://twigfiddle.com/jbde9m

```
{% for item in page.header.table %}
     <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
{% endfor %} 

{# you can also do for item in page.header.table.0.content #}
{% for item in (page.header.table|first).content %}
     <h1>{{item.value}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And if I had another title and content.
How would I do to display them in an html <table>?

Comment: by doing another loop